# create complex kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

here are my logs:

**index: purchase**

```
 {details: { name: john, corID: 12345678 , UUID : 555gotr}}
 {details: { name: bill, corID: 96657545 , UUID : ggg777}}
```

**other indexes**

```
{town: NY, ID: 12345678 }
{a:b , v: g}
{a: hi, b: 12345678}
{g:f , k:ggg777 }
```

I would like to create a dashboard where a the user can enter a  name, process will search in `purchase` index  for `details.name=<name>` ,  extract `details.UUID` and search in all other indexes for logs which contain  the `details.UUID`

example for above details:

**user enters:**  john

**kibana dashboard result:**
(all logs which have `12345678`)

```
{details: { name: john, corID: 12345678 , UUID : 555gotr}}
{town: NY, ID: 12345678 }
{a: hi, b: 12345678}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create multiple visualisations, some on purchase index and some of other index, then search in the navbar text input ,12345678 and each visualisation will show the documents on specific index.